# Wifi taking too long to connect

Tags: windows-10, wifi-driver

To clear some space on my SSD,  I ran the following commands

```
TAKEOWN /F "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository" /R

ICACLS "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository" /T /L /GRANT *S-1-1-0:F

RD /s /Q "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\"
```

right after this I got notification to update the display, Bluetooth and WiFi driver and when I updated and restarted all these drivers my laptop was taking too long to connect to WiFi

I tried uninstalling(using device manager) and reinstalling WiFi driver of same version and previous version but the problem persists.

I currently have installed Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 v19.51.28.1 driver installed

Comment: If you have System Restore enabled, I'd recommend you go back in time and restore Windows as it was before you deleted all those files, because obviously it did more bad than good... If that's not an option, you can try Snappy Driver Installer (here: https://sdi-tool.org/) to help you find the best drivers (check the "older but better" box, it works very well) for your PC, and get your WiFi back on track. My advice when running SDI the first time: only download the index, not the whole driver collection, then let the program scan your PC for drivers to update.